# Group by for an existing record

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table that looks like this

```
RepID     Code   Target
1         A      P2
1         B      L7
1         C      L7
1         D      J3
3         A      P5
3         R      H3
4         D      L7
4         F      K4
```

I want to group by so the end result look like this

for Target **L7**

```
RepID    Code    TargetExist
1        B,C     1
3        NULL    0
4        D       1
```

I tried this query but did not work for me

```
SELECT RepID, Agg_Str(Code, ','), CASE WHEN Target='L7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY RepID
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this.

Every column has to be an aggregate or in the group by

```
SELECT RepID
      , Code = string_agg(IIF(Target='L7',code,null), ',')
      , TargetExists = max(CASE WHEN Target='L7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY RepID
```

Results

```
RepID   Code        TargetExists
1       B,C         1
3       NULL        0
4       D           1
```